# belogs to many Relation between 3 entities laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 entities Category, Post and Page. the relation between Category and Post is belongs to many ( and it works fine) and the relation between Page and Category is also belongs to many (it works fine too). now i want to retrieve all categories' posts in a page .Is there a way to make a directly relation between Page and Post?
my tables structure :

```
categories: int id string title.

posts: int id text content.

categories_posts: int id int category_id int post_id.

pages: int id string title.

pages_categories: int id int page_id int category_id.
```

Comment: That is a bit tricky can you try following code? 


`class Page extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post',
            'App\PagesCategory',
            'category_id', // Foreign key on pages_categories table...
            'id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on pages table...
            'user_id' // Local key on pages_categories table...
        );
    }
}`

Comment: I have already tried that but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think a chain of 'join' will do the purpose

in Page Model:

```
public function posts()
{
return $this->join('pages_categories','pages_categories.page_id','=','pages.id')
->join('categories','categories.id','=','pages_categories.category_id')
->join('categories_posts','categories_posts.category_id','categories.id')
->join('posts','categories_posts.post_id','posts.id')->select('posts.*');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. a chain of join won't be slow ?

Comment: i join is the faster way to get table connected ... i don't thing there is a faster way to do this